# What does "ROCKET IN MY ROLLS" mean on a toy slot machine?

Tags: phrases, expressions, slogan, products

When I was a kid, I got one of these one lucky Christmas. Needless to say, it fascinated me for endless hours and was a major highlight of my childhood. (Which perhaps might be a bit sad, but I remember it as a very happy memory.)

However, I could never figure out what the text meant:

> ROCKET IN MY ROLLS

Rockets... in its rolls? There were no rocket symbols used. And what does that even refer to? Is it the name of the actual slot machine it's a miniature version of? If so, what does it mean originally? Is it even English?

[image]

Comment: It was a bit of a pun.  First off it's a play on "rock-n-roll", but it also is likely playing on "rocketing around in a Rolls Royce".  And, of course, when you play the game it literally rolls (the wheels) and the sound and light can be equated to "rocketing".

Comment: I took it to mean "rocket (v.)" to do something very swiftly "He rocketed through his work." and "a roll" is a revolution (rolling round - cf."a roll of the dice.") and refers to the motion of the slot machine's wheels, and, by extension, "the chances of winning."